# Problems with database not creating a profile for the player in roblox

Tags: database, lua, roblox

So i am having a problem with the database not creating a profile for the player resulting in no changes happening when joining

the database code am using was from a youtube tutorial after i bashed my head against the wall for hours and it still doesnt work what is the problem here and why is it failing and making

```lua
local PlayerDataHandler = {}


local dataTemplate = {
    Cash = 0,
    Inventory = {}
}

local ProfileService = require(game.ServerScriptService.ProfileService)
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

local ProfileStore = ProfileService.GetProfileStore(
    "PlayerProfile",
    dataTemplate
)

local Profiles = {}

local function playerAdded(player)
    local profile = ProfileStore:LoadProfileAsync("Player_"..player.UserId)
    
    if profile then 
        profile:AddUserId(player.UserId)
        profile:Reconcile()
        
        profile:ListenToRelease(function()
            Profiles[player] = nil
            
            player:Kick()
        end)
        
        if not player:IsDescendantOf(Players) then
            profile:Release()   
        else
            Profiles[player] = profile
        end
    else
        player:Kick()
    end
end

function PlayerDataHandler:Init()
    for _, player in game.Players:GetPlayers() do
        task.spawn(playerAdded, player)
    end
    
    game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(playerAdded)
    
    game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
        if Profiles[player] then
            Profiles[player]:Release()
        end
    end)
end


local function getProfile(player)
    assert(Profiles[player], string.format("Profile doesn't exist for player"))
    
    return Profiles[player]
end

function PlayerDataHandler:Get(player, key)
    local profile = getProfile(player)
    assert(profile.Data[key], string.format("Data doesn't exist for okey: %s", key))
    
    return profile.Data[key]
end

function PlayerDataHandler:Set(player, key, value)
    local profile = getProfile(player)
    assert(profile.Data[key], string.format("Data doesn't exist for okey: %s", key))
    
    assert(type(profile.Data[key]) == type(value))
    
    profile.Data[key] = value
end

function PlayerDataHandler:Update(player, key, callback)
    local profile = getProfile(player)
    
    local oldData = self:Get(player, key)
    local newData = callback(oldData)
    
    self:set(player, key, newData)
end


return PlayerDataHandler
```

[image: picture of the explorer]

[image: picture of the error am currently getting]